# select statment with case condition sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have an employee table

```
empname code1  code2
 kiran   aa    bng
 manju   yh    yh
 anu     yu01  yuo1
```

now i need  to  do an select statement like this

```
SELECT case when (employee.code1)=''
 then         
      mappingcode.Code            
   else             
then
       employee.code2          
   end as Code   
 FROM 
employee  where bic1=  'kiran'
```

but i get an error,

in my  project i have an similar issue, just  ot  expalin the probem i have  defined  the  issue

what i need to  do here first check for code1  if null  set its  value  from other table   if not  assign  code2 value  to  code1

code1-->code2

**i get an error  as  The multi-part identifier employee.code2** 
hope my Question is clear

can anyone  help me teh syntax  how  to achive it.

thanks

Prince

Comment: What is the structure of the `mappingcode` and `employee` tables?

Comment: Are you sure the error message is about `employee.code2`? From your script it seems the offending part should be `mappingcode.Code`, because you are not joining `mappingcode` into your query. Either the query you've posted is incomplete or the error message isn't connected with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the select, i think this will help you:

```
    SELECT empname, CASE 
WHEN employee.code1 IS NULL THEN mappingcode.code
ELSE
employee.code2 end as Code1
FROM employee INNER JOIN mappingcode ON employee.empname = mappingcode.empname
```

If you want the update, try this:

```
    Update employee set code1 = x.code from (SELECT empname, CASE 
WHEN employee.code1 IS NULL THEN mappingcode.code
ELSE
employee.code2 end as code
FROM employee INNER JOIN mappingcode ON employee.empname = mappingcode.empname) x 
 inner join employee on employee.empname = x.empname
```

Without knowing more about your schema, i think this is what you are looking for.

Thank you to Andriy for pointing out i had the same select in my post and a little mistake:)

Comment: This is what you get with copy&paste: two absolutely identical pieces of code. :) Other than that, I believe something's wrong with this too: `WHEN employee IS NULL`.

Comment: @Andriy... That is soo true:) Fixing it now:)